# How can automatically upload pictures and videos taken to google drive?

Tags: google-drive

I'm having trouble automatically uploading the picture and video taken with my camera to google drive, I followed the steps on this site: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509#folderab


But I don't have the **Auto Backup** option, I have my gmail account to sync google drive but still no luck, I have a S5 Mini with 4.4.2 android version, if anyone has a step by step or a solution to my problem please give it to me...thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search it can't be done with google drive, the photos taken will be uploaded to google+, so if google+ is deactivated (like I have it) the photos won't upload :(